# Ways to convert cartesian indexing to matrix indexing as in numpy.meshgrid

Tags: python, numpy

I'm building some software that involves a meshgrid created using [`np.meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) and the matrix indexing (that is, setting `` indexing = `ij` ``). However, the function that I'm working on could potentially take meshgrids created using the cartesian indexing (that is, setting `` indexing = `xy` ``). Is there a quick way to go from `` indexing = `xy` `` to `` indexing = `ij` ``). When it's just 2 dimensional, I can simply transpose. However, when I go up to 3D, 4D, etc., transposition wouldn't do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexing` only affects the order of the first two axes. [`swapaxes(0, 1)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html) can be used to reverse the order:

```
In [106]: I,J,K,L = np.meshgrid([1,2,3],['A','B'],[10,20,30,40],['X','Y','Z'], indexing='ij')

In [107]: X,Y,Z,W = np.meshgrid([1,2,3],['A','B'],[10,20,30,40],['X','Y','Z'], indexing='xy')

In [108]: (I.swapaxes(0,1) == X).all()
Out[108]: True

In [109]: (J.swapaxes(0,1) == Y).all()
Out[109]: True

In [110]: (K.swapaxes(0,1) == Z).all()
Out[110]: True

In [111]: (L.swapaxes(0,1) == W).all()
Out[111]: True
```

`swapaxes(0, 1)` converts `xy` to `ij` indexing too (of course):

```
In [112]: (X.swapaxes(0,1) == I).all()
Out[112]: True
```